# mouse selection lost by status update in byobu/tmux

Tags: tmux, iterm, byobu

I'm on Mac 10.7.5 iTerm2, ssh'ing into an Ubuntu machine running byobu 5.12 with tmux 1.7.

The problem is that if I try to select text from the terminal with a mouse, it's gets cleared every time the time gets updated on the bottom right hand side of the status bar. That is, I select fine, then the clock ticks over, and it's cleared again.

Any workaround for this?

Comment: tmux has its own way of dealing with copy-pasting: http://www.rushiagr.com/blog/2016/06/16/everything-you-need-to-know-about-tmux-copy-pasting/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just proposed this tiny fix http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~zekus-one/byobu/trunk/revision/1992 and is waiting for revision. That fixes the issue for me.

You should be able to edit /usr/bin/byobu-status and apply the fix manually while waiting for the official release.

Hope this helps.